# ImproperlyConfigured at admin

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I've seen this question here and I was trying the differents solutions. I mean the one's that is refers to GRAPPELLI because I think the error is around there.

I'm getting this error:

```
Module "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage" does not define a "CachedStaticFiles" attribute/class
```

This error is refers to the line 10 on grappelli/templates/admin/base.html,

```
<link href="{% static "grappelli/jquery/ui/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" %}"
```

**This is my urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**This is my settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'medio.context_processors.basico',
)

GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = 'MY_PROJECT'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'proyecto',
    'userprofile',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'medio.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'medio.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'medio2',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFiles'
```

Comment: What do you get when you run ./manage.py collectstatic -v 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFiles'
```

with

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: Like magic! Thanks @Julian I'm checking this url to know more about the static files! https://mike.tig.as/blog/2011/12/22/django-14-first-thoughts-cachedstaticfilesstorage/ thanks!